# ATI Graphics - iMac 27 - incorrect graphics card reported

Tags: mac, amd-graphics

I using Ubuntu 16.04 on a new iMac retina 2015.
(please don't ask me why)

I am trying to get descent 3d graphics out of my card using AMDGPU.

*I boot using rerind. This is not about fglrx.*

I am currently using the default radeon driver - its buggy at 5k resolution (not surprising) - but usable.

The card is a **R9 M380** according to MAC, but is reported differently in Ubuntu.

On Mac in System information I have :

```
  Chipset Model:    AMD Radeon R9 M380
  Type: GPU
  Bus:  PCIe
  PCIe Lane Width:  x16
  VRAM (Total): 2048 MB
  Vendor:   ATI (0x1002)
  Device ID:    0x6640
  Revision ID:  0x0080
  ROM Revision: 113-C6005R-800
  EFI Driver Version:   01.00.800
```

Where as in Ubuntu 16.04 I have :

```
$ lspci | grep VGA

01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Saturn XT [FirePro M6100] (rev 80)

$ lspci | grep AMD

01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Saturn XT [FirePro M6100] (rev 80)

01:00.1 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Tobago HDMI Audio [Radeon R7 360 / R9 360 OEM]
```

Looking at the wiki page

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_AMD_graphics_processing_units#Radeon_R5.2F7.2F9_M300_Series

The **R9 M380** described suggests it is *GCN 1st gen* (1.0 - Southern Islands).

Where as the **R7 360** on the same page describes it as *GCN 2nd gen* (1.1 - Sea Islands)

And the **FirePro M6100** described here :

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_AMD_graphics_processing_units#FirePro_Mobile_Series

seems to have *GCN 2nd gen*  GCN 1.1

This is quite important as the AMDGPU has a minimum requirement of at least 1.1 (and is disabled) and does not support 1.0. So depending on what it is - I might be able to get it running.

**Question** : *Which card do I really have ?*

**UPDATE :** I have posted this in the Mac Forums :http://www.mac-forums.com/apple-desktops/335312-ati-graphics-imac-27-incorrect-graphics-card-reported.html

**UPDATE :** I have install DPCI Manger as suggested on Mac and it is Contradictory to itself. On the Status page it says :

```
AMD Radeon R9 M380
```

*but* in the PCI List page it says :

```
89501002, 6640, 106B, 014B, Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI], Saturn [Radeon HD 8950]
```

as the VGA compatible display controller! - Holy Moly - Yet another card reported ! I think that's about 4 now.

**UPDATE :** *sudo lshw -* on Ubuntu returns

```
jowan@iMac16:~$ sudo lshw -class display
  *-display               
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: Saturn XT [FirePro M6100]
       vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       version: 80
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm pciexpress msi vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=radeon latency=0
       resources: irq:27 memory:a0000000-afffffff memory:b0000000-b07fffff ioport:3000(size=256) memory:d1600000-d163ffff memory:d1640000-d165ffff
```

*So* .. the only commonality I can see at the moment is the *Saturn* model name, which the M6100 has. The M6100 is based on the Radeon R9 M280X. I sincerely hope it isn't a Radeon HD 8950, as that put's it on the same ball park as the M380.

Comment: https://support.apple.com/kb/SP731?viewlocale=en_US&locale=en_US suggets you likely have the M380. The iMac uses a mobile version of the graphics chip, so you definitely wouldn't have an R7 360, which would be a full PCIx GPU card.

Comment: @dobey thanks. What about it being a FirePro M6100 ? which seems to be listed here : http://support.amd.com/en-us/kb-articles/pages/workstation-graphics-drivers.aspx the trouble is AMDGPU would probably look for it being the right card ?

Comment: It's almost certainly not a FirePro M6100, as I see no evidence that Apple ever used one in an iMac. If Apple says it's the M380, then it's the M380. I'm not sure why Linux is saying it's something else.

Comment: ok - so any idea how do I make Ubuntu report the correct card ? phoronix test suite also reports M6100.

Comment: Install 14.04 instead and use the fglrx drivers? It sounds like your card isn't supported by amdgpu, and radeon doesn't quite state the correct value for what your card is. It doesn't seem like AMD supports that chipset with the new amdgpu based drivers. If you're ok with whatever "buggy" aspects you mentioned in your question, then stick with 16.04. To use proprietary drivers that support your card, you will need to use 14.04 instead.

Comment: think I'll stick with it. I'm sure (please lord) that some one is going to sort out the fglrx / catalyst / AMDGPU /  mess soon. There is a lot of people affected. The community driver is good for now :)

Answer (score 0):

You have a FirePro M6100.

You can see this by looking at the MAC output where it states that there is 2GByte of video memory. A Radeon R9 M380 would have 4GByte.

Linux and Phoronix are reporting this because this is what the card is telling them.

Comment: I'm not sure I entirely believe that. Something some where must be identifying itself as M6100 - some part of it must be, but not all of it. If this IS the case - then MAC have clearly miss described this machine !

Comment: If you have troubl e believing this download and run DCPI Manager under OSX and see what it says.

Comment: It does report it as an R9 M380 !

Comment: Please edit your question to include the output of DCPI manager under OSX and the output of sudo lshw -class display under Ubuntu

Comment: I have updated the answer - YET ANOTHER card reported ! Radeon HD 8950 - holy moly